# Dependency Walker: Error Opening File

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, dependencies

I am using Dependency Walker to try and resolve a .dll error. I have a main project that includes many libraries. Dependency Walker shows an error on 4 .dlls:

`Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2).`

Which is funny because the output of Visual Studio's linker clearly shows that the libraries have been found. Everything in the .exe is linked properly (all symbols are resolved). When I start the application I get a Windows error:

`The program has stopped working.`

I'm using the same API that was discussed in this question: [Win32 DLL importing issues (DllMain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925726/win32-dll-importing-issues-dllmain/4163102#comment16506612_4163102). If I build in debug mode I get the error that is quoted about memory initialization.

Are the .dlls being included or is the problem that Dependency Walker can't see the .dlls? Is this because the relevant libraries are import libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .dlls were being included. Dependency Walker just didn't know where to find the files. Adding the library directories to the system `PATH` variable allowed Dependency Walker to find the libraries.

Comment: I know it has been a long time, but do you remember how did you solve the issue? Why did the program stop working? I am having the same problem now and its driving me crazy

Comment: There were two problems. The first one was simply that Dependency Walker wasn't able to find the libraries because it was not aware of their location on disk. The second problem is tied to the Abaqus ODB API. If you are using this API, I can elaborate on the specific issue further.