# Call a function before static member allocation

Tags: c++, design-patterns, memory-management, static-members

I am using a 3rd party API that overrides the memory management functions found in the C Runtime libraries. In order for everything to work properly, I must make a call to initialize the API before any memory allocations take place.

The project I am working on uses a static Factory object that is dynamically initialized before any of the code in the main file is executed.

How can I ensure that the API will be initialized before the static Factory object?

Comment: You can't guarantee the order global statics are initialized in. Function local statics are initialized before they are used, so often global statics can be put into an `instance()` function, and then you can control the order in which they are called.

Comment: @BoBTFish The factory object is a static member of a class. Does that change anything?

Comment: It doesn't change anything as far as order of initialization is concerned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ standard library runs into the same problem: it has to ensure that `cin`, `cout`, etc. are initialized before any code, including constructors for static objects, uses them. The trick that was invented for handling this situation can also solve yours. In a header file that gets included **first** in every translation unit (well, every translation unit that has static objects with dynamic initializers):

```
class init_library {
public:
    init_library() { if (counter++ == 0) initilaize_the_library(); }
private:
    static int counter;
};

static init_library i_library;
```

and in one translation unit you have to provide a definition of `init_library::counter`.

This will put a static object of type `init_library` in every translation unit that pulls in the header. Its initialization will happen **before** any other initialization in that same translation unit (because its #include directive came **first** -- don't forget that!), and the first time that one of these objects gets initialized, it will call the code to initialize the library. (Note that this code is not thread-safe; making it thread-safe is straightforward)

This is known as the "nifty counter trick".

Comment: You are right. In Visual Studio, `_initterm` will initialize the static members associated with the standard library. I think static allocation is ok, but dynamic allocation is what upsets the API.

Comment: cool, +1, but as you said, it's not thread safe. I am working on a library which runs on an AIX based supercomputer and after last upgrade of the system + IBM compilers + libs it turned out that MPI is spawning threads before initializing my C++ library (and before main), so code in my global static factories was crashing. So I moved all of those static global factories to a function which client code has to call before using my lib. Problem solved.

Comment: @Derek - yes, there are compiler-specific hooks to control initialization and cleanup. That's why I said "the trick that was invented" and not "the trick that's used" `<g>`.

Comment: +1 for "compiler-specific hooks". I've been trying to figure out the magic behind `_initterm`.

Comment: @Derek - it was invented by Jerry Schwarz, the designer and implementor of the iostreams library for cfront.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you very much for sharing this. Will there be much overhead including this in about 40 libraries? I suppose I don't have much choice.

Comment: I really appreciate your time, sir! This fixed my problem!

Answer (score 5):

You should move your static factory objects initilization to a static function and call that function after initializing 3rd party lib as a first thing in main.

Comment: Is it really that simple? Nothing internal is initializing the Factory object from what I can tell.

Comment: It is necessary if you want your program to always behave as expected. Google and read about static objects initialization fiasco.

Comment: @Derek, static objects are initialized by hidden code that runs before `main` unless they're local to a function, and you can't control the order that they're initialized. Statics that are local to a block of code do not get initialized until that block of code is executed.

Comment: @MarkRansom - it's not quite that bad. Statics that are defined in the same translation unit are initialized in the order of their definition. What you can't (portably) control is the order of initialization **across** multiple translation units.

Comment: Umm, no, static objects are typically initialized **before** entry into `main`, so calling the library's initialization from inside `main` would be too late.

Comment: .. unless they are local, in which case they are initialised on first call to function they are local to

Comment: @Derek - yes, allocation is separate from initialization. Allocation must happen before initialization, otherwise there's nothing to initialize.

Comment: "unless they are local" yes, of course. The issue here primarily revolves around file-static objects, and I really don't want to clutter the discussion with that qualifier.

Comment: Sorry, thought that was a stupid question :). I was thinking about it the wrong way. Right, the variables must be allocated and then initialized. I guess I was having a problem because I think the API only cares about when you use `new`.

Comment: Whoops, misread the answer. Yes, if you move initialization of **every** static object with dynamic initialization into `main` you can ensure that the library's initializer gets called first. For small programs that could be feasible, but it's a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Currently, the initialization is nicely isolated from the `main`, and I'd like to keep it that way. The main file doesn't directly use the factory.